# The meaning of the phrase in the quote

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> "Muhammad Ali shook up the world. And the world
> is better for it," said U.S. President Barack Obama and
> his wife Michelle.

What does this part mean "And the world is better for it"? This is a passage from the article on the Muhammad Ali's death

Answer (score 1):

**Muhammad Ali shook up the world.**

This means Muhammad Ali caused changes to happen in the world.

**And the world is better for it.**

This means the Obamas believe we now have a better world because of the changes that Muhammad Ali caused to happen. The changes were positive and beneficial.